# How to assert execution time in Google Test?

Tags: c++, assert, googletest

I am using Google's C++ testing framework Gtest. I would like to test a function against its
execution time, e.g. function foo() fails if its execution is longer than 3ms. 
I could not find an ASSERT statement to achieve this. Does gtest not include such a feature ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably doesn't exist as the bug is still open:
http://code.google.com/p/googletest/issues/detail?id=348

Comment: The bug was recently rejected and closed

Answer (score 6):

Why not to use such simple solution?

```
//pseudo code
clock_t t = clock();
foo();
const double work_time = (clock() - t) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
ASSERT_TRUE(work_time <= 0.003);
```

Comment: I'm afraid the precision is not high enough.. Something like `QueryPerformanceCounter()` would be better.

Comment: It just meta code, you can use what you want instead of clock.

Comment: Yeah you should point it out, as usually `clock()` has low precision.

Comment: What if `foo()` gets stuck in an infinite loop?  The test will never exit.  That's the key reason to need time limits on tests.  Timing how long a test takes (as you've shown) is quite easy, but it's the stopping of a runaway test (without causing memory leaks that might be detected by other tests) that gets a little more complicated.

Comment: @HankSchultz I not care about time limits, because of tests are run by `ctest` which has time maximum for test, and if test exceed time limit it will be killed, and `ctest` run by `buildbot`, which also have time limit per test. But if you run test by hands it may be problem for you.

Comment: What if it does not terminate? You need to launch a separate thread and wait only on the timer, terminate the test thread and report timeout if timer is timed out and it's still running.

Comment: @Viet I use buildbot/ctest both of them have timeouts, that is common functionality for test runners/CI systems, so I expect that unit test should not care about this.

Comment: Right. Using the test system timeout feature is the best to keep tests clean and self-contained.

Comment: In C++11 you can use `chrono`:
`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();` and
`std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time).count();`

Comment: There is an [elapsed_time function](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/testing.html#TestSuite::elapsed_time), that could be helpful in this case. But, unfortunately, it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to use the stats that GoogleTest prints out for this. This is at the program level, but you could probably do the same in `TearDownTestCase()` to sanity check speed in a subset. This is because there is a TestCase-level `elapsed_time` member function.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    auto result(RUN_ALL_TESTS());
    ::testing::internal::TimeInMillis elapsed(
        ::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->elapsed_time());
    ASSERT_LT(elapsed, measurePerf ? 180 * 1000 : 215 * 1000);
    return result;
}
```

Representative results:

> [==========] 338 tests from 18 test cases ran. (207723 ms total) [ 
>   PASSED  ] 338 tests.
>
> YOU HAVE 13 DISABLED TESTS
>
> FrameworkTest.cpp(39): error:
>   Expected:  (elapsed) < (measurePerf ? 190 * 1000 : 170 * 1000),
>   actual: 207723 vs 170000